# Setting up Kerberos in python in Ubuntu machine

Tags: python, authentication, kerberos

I need to setup a kerberos server on my Ubuntu machine for the authentication of users. I tried using pykpass for the same, but was facing some problems in installing the python module. Is there some other way to do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install python-kerberos
```